# Framework Compatibility Issue While Installing MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf from Nuget

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/awooo-ph/sfc.gate)
project from github. But when it comes to installing to MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf for wpftoolkit. it fails due to compatibility issue.Here is the full error:

> "Error Could not install package 'MaterialDesignColors 1.1.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

I tried with changing the project target framework but it did not work.

Could any body please help in resolving this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Any body please will help as I am very new

Comment: I believe the toolkit folder is empty that's why its throwing this error so let the owner of repo to upload the files necessary

Comment: thanks for your message.
I added required projects from official site and then change the target framework of my main project. it now install the MaterialDesignThemes but still missing assembly 
 reference error in building the project.

Comment: assembly reference error can be solved by adding reference using reference manager. Try this:

Right-Click on References then Add Reference from there u can add reference